# Glass Carboy Drying Tips

Tags: carboy

Does anyone know of any tips to help a 5 gallon glass carboy dry faster? I have it in a bay window in the sun, upside down in a carboy drying rack. It is mostly dry in 24 hours but there is still condensation built up on the inside walls. It takes anywhere from 2-4 days for that condensation to dry. I store my carboy in the basement so it has to be completely dry to keep it from molding.

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer because I haven't tried it.  Perhaps a desiccant packet would help after that initial 24-hour drying period?  Maybe something like this: http://amzn.to/if9lgl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I leave mine upside down until there is just condensation left inside (no more drips). 
Then if you lay it on its side the condensation will evaporatefrom the bottom side. Roll over and repeat. Mine will usually dry in about a day this way.

Comment: Bingo. Find a spot under a sunny window and it works in a couple hours. Right-side-up works well here, since water vapor heated by sunlight rises.

Answer (score 2):

Never tried it but I suppose you could point a small fan into the opening of the car boy. I have a ton laying around because I work on media center enclosures and computers for a living. I've seen **very** small fans (like 4 inches) at my local big box / office supply stores if you don't have anything lying around.

Answer (score 1):

I use a hairdryer to warm the sides of the carboy to remove residual condensation. Works great with plastic carboys (heavy-walled Nalgene) and my glass 3 gal.

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your situation, I'd wait until the drops of moisture are out of the carboy, then turn it right-side up and leave it in the sunshine for a day until it's gone.